# Bridge not reaching internal network for OpenVPN Ethernet Bridge in a Ubuntu 22.04 VM on ESXi

Tags: linux, openvpn, bridge

I want to set up OpenVPN Ethernet Bridging. I'm following the steps from https://openvpn.net/community-resources/ethernet-bridging/ and after setting configuring the bridge as described in https://openvpn.net/community-resources/notes-ethernet-bridging-windows-client-linux-server/, I cannot reach any machines from my internal network. (i.e.: `ping 10.5.0.2` is only returning `Destination Host Unreachable`)

Any idea why this is happening?

It is worth mentioning that I set up everything inside a Ubuntu 22.04 VM on ESXi 8.0.0 and promiscuous mode is activated on the vSwitch tried the Ethernet Adapter on both E1000 and VMXNET3.

EDIT: I think it might be an ESXi issue, I tried on a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 22.04 and it worked directly without any issue.

Comment: You probably haven't permitted arp spoofing and promiscious mode on the VM in esxi.

Comment: Besides, are you *certain* that you want bridging? Based on your question I guess you're new to networking  - and the answer is usually that you don't want bridging, but perceive it to be tologically simpler. It ain't.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. As I said, I activated promiscious mode on the vSwitch and PortGroup, isn't it correct?

I went for bridging as it provides assigned IP from a dedicated pool of local IPs as I want to have full two-way reachability without needing weird IPs.

That being said, even if I could solve my problem without bridging, I would still want to understand why it is not working with ESXi while it worked directly by setting it up on a raspberry pi. I will still give it a try by using a dedicated ethernet port through passthrough to see if that solves the issue.

Comment: You get full two way reachability with routing. And none of the drawbacks of extending L2 across the internet.

Comment: Oh alright, will give it a try then :) Also, I tried now using a ethernet port with passthrough instead of through ESXi and it works like a charm.

Comment: I have everything running fine with TAP, but cannot make it run with TUN. I can ping the server using its internal IP, but cannot ping any machine from the internal network. I checked with tcpdump and the ICMP echo is received but I never get a reply from the machine. I temporarily deactivated UFW to check but no lock. I guess I need to configure some routing?

Comment: Ok, finally managed to have it working both ways with tun, by following https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting I'll write down a better answer to my own question.